# Mac OSX API Equivalent To Windows OS

Tags: c++, c, windows, macos, api

I just started migrating to Mac OS X and I wanted to port a couple of tools I wrote for Windows. The question is what is the equivalent for the following:

```
CreateFile()
CreateFileMapping()
MapViewOfFile()
```

I would appreciate if someone could either guide me to a place where I can read about it or if there is some sort of a quick guide for such common questions/problems or simply answer my question.

The language of choice is C/C++ for a command line tool.

Comment: C/C++ is not a language, it's two...

Comment: Let's avoid having irrelevant comments. It's obvious that I am pointing out that I am using C and C++ for the projects. Either have a constructive comment or just don't comment at all. No reason to start a debate over nonsense either.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be rude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of `CreateFile` would be [`open`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/open.2.html). The latter two steps for mapping a file, `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile`, are condensed into one step on Mac OS X, with the [`mmap`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mmap.2.html) function.

Comment: I looked up the functions you suggested and seems that is exactly what I need. I am flagging this as the answer am looking for. Thank you!